# What is the best way to find a subroutine or section of code that does not have an error handler

Tags: parsing, vb6, error-handling

I maintain a large VB6 application and yesterday a customer reports a 'Subscript out of range error' on screen, whereby clicking on it quit the app.

We use a standard error handling routine which throws up a message box and logs the error to file and the fact that neither of these things happened makes me think that the line of code in question does not have any error handling.

Now..how do I go about finding where this line of code is in my project?

I can write something to scan through each file noting when I see `on error...` inside a sub etc, etc. but can anyone think of a better/faster way? Are there any tools out there that do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this (**VB.NET**) code to extract this info (note that coding is a bit quick and dirty but seems to work)

It won't cope with `on error goto 0` and `on error goto [label]` in the same sub routine:

```
Private Sub SearchForNoErrorHandlers(ByVal path As String)

        Dim line As String, subName As String = "", inSub As Boolean = False, handlerFound As Boolean = False

        For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            'Debug.WriteLine(file) 'gives the full path and filename of any files found
            If file.EndsWith(".bas") OrElse file.EndsWith(".cls") OrElse file.EndsWith(".frm") Then
                Using sr As New StreamReader(file)
                    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
                        line = sr.ReadLine
                        'Debug.WriteLine(line)
                        If IsStartOfSub(line) AndAlso Not inSub Then
                            subName = line
                            inSub = True
                            handlerFound = False

                        ElseIf IsEndOfSub(line) AndAlso inSub Then
                            inSub = False
                            If handlerFound = False Then
                                Debug.WriteLine("** No handler found for file {0} in Sub: {1}", file, subName)
                            End If

                        ElseIf line.ToUpper.Contains("ON ERROR") AndAlso inSub Then
                            handlerFound = True

                        End If
                    Loop
                End Using
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Function IsStartOfSub(ByVal line As String) As Boolean
        Dim subTextPosition As Integer = line.ToUpper.IndexOf("SUB ")
        Dim functionTextPosition As Integer = line.ToUpper.IndexOf("FUNCTION ")
        Dim openBracket As Integer = line.IndexOf("(")
        Dim closeBracket As Integer = line.IndexOf(")")
        If subTextPosition >= 0 AndAlso openBracket >= 0 AndAlso closeBracket >= 0 AndAlso closeBracket > openBracket AndAlso openBracket > subTextPosition Then
            Return True
        ElseIf functionTextPosition >= 0 AndAlso openBracket >= 0 AndAlso closeBracket >= 0 AndAlso closeBracket > openBracket AndAlso openBracket > functionTextPosition Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function IsEndOfSub(ByVal line As String) As Boolean
        Return (line.ToUpper.Contains("END SUB") OrElse line.ToUpper.Contains("END FUNCTION"))
    End Function
```